# Save environment declared with \NewDocumentEnvironment to redefine it

Tags: environments, expl3, xparse, definition

I have some environment declared with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, lets call it `oldenv` which I want to redefine in another package, to tweak it a little bit.
However, in the redefinition I want to make use of the old definition of the environment.
With the usual strategy, you would say something like

```
\cs_new_eq:NN \oldenv    \__package_save_oldenv:w
\cs_new_eq:NN \endoldenv \__package_save_endoldenv:w
...
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { oldenv } { ... }
{
% Use \__package_save_oldenv:w here to refer to the old definiton
}
{
...
}
```

which works fine. However, the `oldenv` environment has been declared with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, and thus the `\oldenv` expands to

```
\oldenv=\protected
macro:->\__xparse_start_env:nnnnn { o }{oldenv}{\__xparse_grab_D:w []}{}{}.
```

so making a simple copy of this is not sufficient, since the actual meaning of the environment seems to be stored somewhere internal to the `xparse` package.

I also thought about using the hook managment system to just do something at beginning or ending of the `oldenv`, but since I want to change the signature of `oldenv` as well, this is also not an option.

**Is there some intended way to make a 'deep' copy of such an environment, to subsequently redefine it whilst safely having access to the old variant of the environment?**

---

I'm also fine if the answer is a simple 'No', as this would require hacking into the internals of `xparse`, which I do not want to do in this case.
E.g. simply copying the old definition in this case would be sufficient for me, but of course this is not a general nor elegant solution to this kind of problem.

Also, I would be happy with a LaTeX3 way to do this.

Comment: A `\NewCommandCopy`-based solution seems like it should work. Have a look at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/735.

Comment: it sounds odd that you want to change the signature of an environment of another package.